# Can't see methods in DLL... why?

Tags: c#, dll

Can't see methods in DLL... why?

I developed a DLL in C#

When I am trying to call it I get:

System.EntryPointNotFoundException: Unable to find an entry point named:

It means that DLL doens't export any methods visible from DLL. Dumpbin doesn't show any methods either:

dumpbin.exe -exports ActiveXTest.dll
Dump of file ActiveXTest.dll
File Type: DLL
  Summary
        2000 .reloc
        2000 .rsrc
        2000 .text

What's wrong????

The DLL looks ok.. according to documentation:

```
namespace Kosmala.Michal.ActiveXTest
        public static void setHooks()
        {
        ....
        }
```

Here is how I call it:

```
namespace IWFHotkeyStarter
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("D:\\work\\iwf\\_ctrl-tab-modless_dlg_testing\\activex\\VSProjects\\AcriveXSourceCode\\bin\\Debug\\ActiveXTest.dll")]
        public extern static void setHooks();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program p = new Program();
            p.run();
        }
        private void run(){
            Console.WriteLine("run<<");
            setHooks();
            Console.WriteLine("run>>");    
        }
    }
}
```

Please help

Comment: Have you tried using the "add a reference" option.

Comment: Wait, I just realized.  Is your DLL managed code?  If so, then as vash47 said, just add a reference.  Don't do the DLLImport!  That is for unmanaged dlls usually.

Comment: @Vash47 you should have done an answer - another user beat you to it and you can't accept comments as answers.  :)

Answer (score 4):

Your DLL is managed code (written in C#). Classic DLLs like containers of ActiveX controls are unmanaged code and organized in another way.

To use a managed DLL in a managed project, add a reference to it or load it at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

As Mario states, .Net assemblies expose libraries and classes in a different way and so tools like DumpBin won't show anything - if you want to peek inside your assembly then give [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) a try.

As for how to call your managed assembly, the method you have shown ([DllImport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984739%28VS.71%29.aspx)) is used for interops / calling unmanaged code.  To call a method in another managed assembly all you need to do is add an assembly reference and you should be able to see the method just fine.

Another thing to note that in C# all methods must belong to a class, so your example will probably look more like this:

```
namespace Kosmala.Michal.ActiveXTest
public class Hooks
{
    public static void setHooks()
    {
    }
}
```

Using the method:

```
using namespace Kosmala.Michal.ActiveXTest;
namespace IWFHotkeyStarter
{
    class Program
    {
        // ...
        private void run()
        {
            Hooks.setHooks();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok….

1) I added reference to the DLL
2) commented out [DllImport("D:\\work\\iwf\\_ctrl-tab-modl

..............Now I get 

Unhandled Exception: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'IWFHotkeyStarter.Program' from assembly 'IWFHotkeyStarter, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because the method  'setHooks' has no implementation (no RVA).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @michaels123 You should also remove the `extern` declaration of `setHooks` in your `Program` class - you don't need to declare methods using `extern` for other referenced .Net assemblies.

Comment: Ok… I got it..Thank you… Now I have another problem. This hook is a global hot key handler and it looks like after I set it once, this code is not loaded anymore and my method is not called when a user presses the hot key….. maybe I need to write a daemon process which will be always in memory?

Comment: @michaels I'm not sure that I understand - you may be better off asking a new question for your new problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an Interface then the setHooks() method you are trying to call make sure it is declared in the interface.